# Data import wizard library for .Net?

Tags: c#

Does anyone know of a 3rd party data import wizard that can be embedded into applications? It should import from Excel, Access, SQLServer, csv, tab-separated flat file, XML, Oracle etc. We have a fixed data structure within our application and the user should be able to configure the wizard to match his/her import fields to our own data structure.

The wizard should be a library of sorts – preferably a .Net type library. We may want to have it both web-based and desktop based (hence we may need an ASP.Net controls version and a Winforms version). We may also want integration with WPF and Silverlight.

If there’s no UI wizard available, does anyone know of a non-UI library that supports easily configurable import from many, many different datasources?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution would be to use **SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)**

The client can develop the custom package to be run, and the system can run that package in order to import the data.

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem here is that the requirements are nearly impossible to fulfill in a generic way that is still easy enough to use for an end user.

Any import tool would have to be programmed to know a great deal about your data structures, relationships, and business logic.

The actual act of performing the import or having a few screens to step through this is so minor in comparison (usually less than 5% of the work) that there's almost no point in building a "generic" tool for other coders to use.

Now, if you don't mind giving a lot of complexity to your end users AND allowing them to be able to "forget" about your business logic and potentially screw up the imports then by all means hand the something like SSIS.

However, if you need to control what goes in, validate it, and generally make sure it's not going to crater your system then you'll have to code this one yourself.